# Translation for date from / date da

Tags: translation, vocabulary

I need to translate "date from / date to" to Italian in a report (see picture). 

 
Is it correct to translate "date from / date to" as "Data di / Data da" ?
Or is it rather "Data da / Data a" ?

Or would you rather use "a partire da  / entro", or something else ?

[image: Report]

Comment: What about the most natural solution, a simple “da / a”? Or is it important to spell out that it is a date to be inserted (as opposed to an hour or a month, say)?

Comment: @DaG 5: Interesting, yes, sounds more natural. No, it's not important to spell out in this case, so shorter is definitely better ;)

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: I agree, "da/a" is a good solution. Otherwise you could write "inizio/fine" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I think is better to write: "Da Data:" and "a Data:". I'm Italian :D

Comment: Interesting, word sequence reversed ;) I think just da/a would do nicely.

Comment: Yes is a nice idea too. But you write : "datum von,date de,date from", you need,i think,to use "da data" like this (datum von,date de,date from,da data). but is your application and you know what is better for you :)

Comment: I concur, and I actually did that, albeit for consistency reasons only. Though it would have been smarter to just omit datum/date/data everywhere, because that uses less room in the column titles, which can create a free-space-problem (not in this example).

Comment: I agree. Actually, I would have used "Dal/Al", which is the most common combination when referring to dates.

Answer (score -3):

"***Date from***" as you can see from the online dictionary **Word reference** can be translated with ***risalire a*** whereas "***date to***" with ***datare***.

For more examples I suggest you to look at it here http://www.wordreference.com/enit/date

Comment: *Risalire a* is clearly not what was meant in the question (the OP just wanted a label for an input form)

Comment: @Denis Nardin: I figured as much all on my own.

Comment: @StefanSteiger I imagined you did, but I like to give explanations when I downvote. Moreover this answers are kept for future reference, so it's better to be clearer.